# Monero daemon sees deposit but doesnt record it

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

Coding a wallet for my website.  I built a testnet and stagenet wallet.  Both versions same issue so I think it's me.  Utilizing xmr.to for test coins and the node address.

I start the wallet RPC like:

```
/home/testuser/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.16.0.3/monero-wallet-rpc --daemon-address 18.133.59.45:28081 --trusted-daemon
--rpc-bind-port 12388 --disable-rpc-login --log-level 2 --wallet-file /home/testuser/testwallet --prompt-for-password --testnet
```

This is up and running with no issues and getting new blocks received.  I also tried using `monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.15.0.1` as I thought that could be the problem.  I send coins from xmr.to, see the payment ID on xmrchain and confirmations. The wallet, started above, sees it almost instantly:

```
2020-08-29 18:23:39.557 D Decrypted payment ID: <...>
2020-08-29 18:23:39.557 D Payment found in pool: <...> / <d939...7182> / 1000000000000
```

It shows that it got an incoming transaction but only that one time, never again.
The problem is the coins on both testnet and stagenet never show in my wallet.  This is after 10 transactions and 2 days of trying.

My wallet shows the response:

```
Refresh done, blocks received: 0, balance (all accounts): 0.000000000000, unlocked: 0.000000000000
```

My script to check incoming deposits:

```
def checkincomming(lastchecked):
"""
Get rpc incomming deposts
:param lastchecked:
:return:
"""

rpc_input = {
    "method": "get_bulk_payments",
    "params": {"payment_ids": False,
               "min_block_height": lastchecked}
}

# add standard rpc values
rpc_input.update({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "0"})

# execute the rpc request
response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=json.dumps(rpc_input),
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPDigestAuth(rpcusername, rpcpassword))
print(response)
response_json = response.json()

return response_json

x = checkincomming(lastchecked=1540301)
print(x)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) daemons don't process txs, wallets do. 2) please update your question with the RPC method you are calling (i.e. the source of `monero_checki_ncomming_deposits_testnet.py`).

Comment: the monero wallet cli would show it, and it shows 0 balance and i sent 10 transactions over 2 days..the rpc was able to see it but not record it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with dEBRUYNE's help on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/iixld3/monero_rpc_daemon_sees_deposit_but_never_records/g39t619?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Basically the wallet created block was too high and by lowering it I could scan for new transactions in the lower block heights.

I used the command:

```
monero-wallet-cli --testnet set refresh-from-blockheight <blocknumber>
```

where `blocknumber` is lower than current block height (I put 10% lower).

The downside is past transactions I sent are not recorded still, but new ones are. I'm unsure why yet.

Comment: Set the block height to a height before your first tx. The reason you probably still have some missing is you have not gone back far enough.

Comment: ok thanks! Today got the error  Wallet initialization failed: std::bad_alloc when I went back to it. Is it related?